# Does the gamblers fallacy not apply to Bayesian probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

Bayesian probability is an alternative probability theory that uses data from past outcomes to predict future outcomes. Do they have some work-around for the gamblers fallacy or do they just ignore it?

Or is Bayesian probability literally just the gamblers fallacy by another name?

Comment: No, Bayesian probability is not just a routine fallacy.

Comment: There is nothing particularly Bayesian (as opposed to frequentist) about "using data from past outcomes to predict future outcomes".

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Bayesian probability is typically only relevant for dependent events.  That is, if A and B are independent events, then $p(A|B) = p(A)$, and there is no need to invoke a special formula to compute $p(A|B).$  The point of [this Gambler's Fallacy article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) is that future events are independent of previous events.  So, since independent rather than dependent events are involved, Bayesian probability doesn't seem relevant to me.

Comment: One of the implications of Bayesian logic is that if a coin comes up heads ten times in a row, it is time to check your assumption that you are working with a fair coin.  This is not a formal part of the theory, but it is part of the practice of Bayesian thinking.

Comment: @DougM This is also an implication of frequentist methods of inference.

Comment: All critters use "data from past outcomes to predict future outcomes"; Natural Selection weeds out those critters who aren't good at prediction, so we are descended from critters who aren't good at it. [Bayesian statistics in a theory that seeks to explain how good predictions are made](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2017.0792).

Comment: @SimonCrase Did you really mean to say "we are descended from critters who *aren't* good at it"?

Comment: @Michael -- Well spotted. We are descended from critters who are good at it.

Comment: @hermancain Bayesian analysis is not an "alternative to probability", it is an alternative method to doing statistics.

Comment: It seems that there is a belief that Bayesian probabilists are better than non-Bayesian probabilists, and that they have a better understanding of probabilities as they use "Bayes Formula". Truth is, conditional probability and Bayes formula are basic tools from precalculus textbooks and any probabilist masters them

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In fact, a Bayesian approach is the exact opposite of the gambler's fallacy.

The gambler's fallacy supposes that if a certain event has happened more often than expected in a series of independent trials¹ - for example, a roulette wheel has been observed to mostly pick red numbers over the last day - it is likely to happen less often in the future, until it has evened out. A fallacious gambler will therefore bet on black in this instance, because a black is "due".

The Bayesian approach is that, supposing there was some initial uncertainty about the exact probability of the event, the fact that it has happened more often provides some evidence for what the actual probability is, and it will tend to revise our estimate for the probability upwards. So a Bayesian gambler will therefore bet on *red*, reasoning that the wheel may be slightly biased in favour of red.

This method of identifying small biases from observations of roulette tables was famously used to "break the bank" at Monte Carlo in the 19th century by [Joseph Jagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Jagger).

---

¹ If the trials are not independent, e.g. cards dealt in blackjack, this may not be fallacious.

Answer (score 9):

The predictive power of Bayesian inference only applies when the probability of an event is *unknown*, such as testing fairness of a possibly biased coin. It does not allow bypassing the gambler's fallacy when the probability is *known* or can be calculated, as is the case with most casino games.